# Regex for my custom URL

Tags: c#, regex, url, routes

Good Day,

I cant create the regex exact for my url:

any-any.test.test2.com or ALL CAPS

http://any-any.test.test2.com or ALL CAPS

https://any-any.test.test2.com or ALL CAPS

can someone please help me how can I make a regex that can accept this url's.

Useful Link:
https://regex101.com/

Note: any means user can input any characters and after first any should have "-" , then all must contain :

.test.test2.com  or

.TEST.TEST2.COM

at the end.

Comment: I am not a C# guru, but I would recommend that you use a library for parsing URLs, and then just check the components of interest in your actual code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry can you please elaborate more?

Comment: What I am saying is that instead of trying to write a URL regex which will cover every edge case you might have, instead use a URL library which exposes an interface you can call to get and check the various components.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I already tried UriKind , but it doesnt fulfill my expectation , so I  think regex is what Im looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
var pattern = "(?i)(https?://)?.+-.+(.test.test2.com)"
```

Usage:

```
var test1 = "any-any.test.test2.com";
var test2 = "ANY-ANY.TEST.TEST2.COM";
var test3 = "http://any-any.test.test2.com";
var test4 = "https://any-any.test.test2.com";

var result1 = Regex.Match(test1, pattern);
var result2 = Regex.Match(test2, pattern);
var result3 = Regex.Match(test3, pattern);
var result4 = Regex.Match(test4, pattern);

Console.WriteLine(result1);
Console.WriteLine(result2);
Console.WriteLine(result3);
Console.WriteLine(result4);
```

Output:

```
any-any.test.test2.com
ANY-ANY.TEST.TEST2.COM
http://any-any.test.test2.com
https://any-any.test.test2.com
```

Comment: how can I remove "any" from (any.test.test2.com) , because it should be any characters too.

Comment: is that what you need? "(?i)(https?://)?[a-z]*-[a-z]*(.test.test2.com)"

Comment: yup , thank you , can you please explain it to me if it is okay?

Comment: the "(?i)" part makes it case insensitive; the (https?://)? block tests for "http://", "https://" or none of them (because of the '?'); the [a-z]* part accepts any characters followed by a "-" and another [a-z]* block of any characters (the '*' means zero or more of the preceding part, in this case: [a-z]); the last part ensure it must end with ".test.test2.com"

Comment: The [a-z] won't match numbers tho. Updated my answer so the "any" parts accepts any alphanumerical character

Comment: Also, while the "asterisk" means zero or more of the preceding, "plus" means one or more of the preceding, ensuring the user must type at least one character in both of the "any" parts you asked for. If that's not the desired behavior, just switch back to asterisks

Answer (score 0):

a simple regex pattern in vim
...-....test.test2.com\c

This will match
"any-any.test.test2.com";
"ANY-ANY.TEST.TEST2.COM"

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

(http(s)?://)?.+-.+.test.test2.com

There is a useful open source tool:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/regulator/

```
Match match = Regex.Match("https://any-any.test.test2.com", "(http(s)?://)?.+-.+\.test.test2.com", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine("OK");
}
```

Comment: Sure. If you set the proper options https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options